# About the capacitance of the capacitor

Tags: capacitance

I would like to ask two questions here , 
1. When a capacitor reaches to its maximum limit charge starts leaking and it ionises the air atoms .  Well is it true ? As I'm not able to get an convincing answer from my colleagues and not on books. 
2. And also if that statement is true then , to reach it's capacitance upto infinity , do we need to place it in vacuum so that it cannot ionises the air and infinity charges can be stored ? 
Any kind of response would be appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: This may be of help. http://qdl.scs-inc.us/2ndParty/Pages/8819.html

Comment: In your question1 are you referring to air capacitor (capacitor using air as its dielectric)?

Comment: Yes the same one Bob D.

Answer (score 0):

1. Once the Voltage at the terminals of the Capacitor, vc, is equal to the Power Supply Voltage, vc = V, the Capacitor is fully charged and the Current stops flowing through the circuit, the Charging Phase is over.  If the circuit is cut at this point, the capacitor will begin to a slow discharge process brought on by the leakage current across the dielectric. The time it takes to get down to 37% is known as the Time Constant.

Comment: Well it's fine but my question is not regarding this , anyways thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The limit to the ability of a capacitor to store charge occurs when, as you point out, the voltage on the plates gets great enough to cause dielectric breakdown of the air or whatever material is used as the dielectric.

For extremely high-voltage applications (as in radio frequency antenna and transmitter design) it becomes necessary to enclose the whole capacitor in a vacuum bottle to prevent this from occurring. The resulting device is called, unsurprisingly, a *vacuum capacitor*.

Even then, however, to store an infinite charge on a capacitor in a vacuum would require either the application of an infinite voltage, or increasing the size of the capacitor plates to infinity, or reducing the spacing between the plates to 1/infinity.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways in which charge can leak off a capacitor; ionizing the air is one of them, but rarely the most important.

A capacitor contains a pair of conducting things (e.g. metal plates) separated by a non-conducting thing (e.g. an air gap, or a dielectric, or a vacuum). But no 'non-conducting' thing is perfectly non-conducting. Charge can move very slowly through all materials, and charge can also move, somewhat more easily, along the surface of any material where it meets the air or vacuum. We call these materials 'insulators' only because their resistance is very high compared to things like metals; but the resistance is not infinite, especially along the surface.

Even a vacuum is conducting in a certain sense. When the voltage is high, electrons will emerge from a conducting surface and fly across the vacuum to the other electrode of the capacitor. Thus no capacitor can reach arbitrarily high voltages.